# Проверка на возможный палиндромом

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, текст

Есть простейшая задача, вот дословное условие:

> Анна написала генератор красивых строк. Она считает строку красивой,
> если она одинаково читается как слева направо, так и справа налево.
> Например, rrr и anna - красивые строки, а abc и adba - нет.
>
> Но она допустила ошибку в коде и генератор выводит не красивые строки,
> а строки, которые можно сделать красивыми, если из каждой удалить
> ровно один символ. По крайней мере, она так думает.
>
> Она просит вас помочь определить, верно ли её предположение.
>
> Формат входных данных
>
> В первой строке вводится строка s состоящая из маленьких латинских
> букв (4≤|s|≤10^3, где |s| - длина строки).
>
> Формат выходных данных
>
> Выведите YES , если можно удалить один символ из строки так, чтобы она
> стала красивой; иначе - NO .
>
> Sample Input 1: abca Sample Output 1: YES
>
> Sample Input 2: abcd Sample Output 2: NO

Мое решение (тоже банальное):

```
def f():
    s = ''.join(input().split())
    n = len(s)
    v = 0
    for i in range(int(n/2)):
        if s[i] != s[n-1-i]:
            v += 1
            if v > 1:
                return('NO')
    if v == 0:
        return('NO')
    if v < 2:
        return('YES')
print(f())
```

НО, к моему удивлению, **код не проходит тесты**. Загвоздка в том, что я не знаю входные данные всех тестов. А глядя на задачку и код понять причину не могу.
Возможно я что-то упускаю?..

Comment: Может *полином*?

Comment: Что ваш код выдаст на ввод `abab`?

Comment: как минимум, upper/lower кейсы, спец и пробельные ваш код не учитывает.

Comment: @EvgeniyShubin так и не должен учитывать `вводится строка s состоящая из маленьких латинских букв`

Comment: проверьте свою функцию на слове `banana` ;)

Comment: Вы пропускаете не 1 символ, а сразу 2, с каждой половины строки. Когда попалось несоответсвие, нужно пропустить 1 символ слева (например a[b]cd-dca)... если совпадение не достигнуто, пробовать пропустить символ справа ( например acd-dc[b]a).

Answer (score 6):

Вариант с перебором

Попробуйте:

```
def foo(text):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        items = list(text)
        items.pop(i)
        
        if items == items[::-1]:
            return 'YES'

    return 'NO'


print(foo("abca"))    # YES
print(foo("abcd"))    # NO
print(foo("abab"))    # YES
print(foo('banana'))  # YES
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(beautiful_string):
    middle = len(beautiful_string) / 2
    is_odd = False
    if (len(beautiful_string) % 2):
        is_odd = True
    pop_count = 0
    index = 0
    reverse_index = -1
    while (index <= middle):
        if (beautiful_string[index] != beautiful_string[reverse_index]):
            if (pop_count > 0):
                return 'NO'

            index += 1
            if (beautiful_string[index] == beautiful_string[reverse_index]):
                pop_count += 1
                middle -= 1
                continue

            index -= 1
            reverse_index -= 1
            if (beautiful_string[index] == beautiful_string[reverse_index]):
                pop_count += 1
                continue
            return 'NO'
        index += 1
        reverse_index -= 1
    if (pop_count == 1):
        return 'YES'
    if (pop_count == 0) and (is_odd):
        return 'YES'
    return 'NO'
```